# Failed to load resource (403) : Hello Analytics Reporting API v4 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics

I'm new to programming so my issues could seem ridiculous to you...

I've tried to run the [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; JavaScript quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js). I succeed in signing in but then no results appear and I get a 403 status code:

[Screenshot : 403 Status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtZND.png)

Could you help me?

Thank you
Alice

Comment: 403 means that the logged in user has no permission to do the requested action. Does the account that you use to log in has at least read permissions for the GA property that you are trying to access ?

Comment: Hello Eike, I have read permissions for this GA property. :-/